# Is the Activity onCreate called with each NewInstance of a fragment inside it?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to generate a new Fragment with the next object in a LinkedList.

When a user clicks `next` I want to reassign a global reference to the next one in the LinkedList and create a fragment with it.

**Problem**

Each time the user clicks next, the object will only be reassigned to the 2nd object in the LinkedList even if there is 5 objects in the LinkedList
ie. `.get(1)`

**Possible cause I am thinking**

Because I get the first object in my LinkedList in the Activity `onCreate`

`parentFlow.getChildElements().get(0)`

When the user clicks `Next`, the global reference is set to `.get(1)` in the Linkedlist, but when `.newInstance()` method gets called, the parent activity `onCreate`called again?

(reassigning the global reference back to `.get(0)` causing an endless cycle)

Is this the correct mechanism of fragment creation? (ie. Activity.onCreate() --> Fragment.onCreate --> Activity.onCreate())?

Code,

**FlowStateActivity.java**

```
public class FlowStateActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements FlowElementFragment.OnFragmentSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = FlowStateActivity.class.getName();

    private Flow parentFlow;
       // Parent Object Containing the LinkedList
    private FlowElement fe;
      // Global reference used to reassign object to next object in LinkedList

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flow_state);

        parentFlow = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("parent");
            // Gets the parent object which contains the LinkedList

            fe = parentFlow.getChildElements().get(0);
                // Assigns fe to the first element in the LinkedList

            FlowElementFragment fragment = FlowElementFragment.newInstance(
                   fe
            );

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.add(R.id.flowstate_fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();

        }

    @Override
        // User selects NEXT inside the Fragment 
    public void onNextSelected(View v) {
        try {
            fe = parentFlow.getChildElements()
                    .get(
                            fe.getNext()
                    );
                // Assigns global reference to next element in the LinkedList

            FlowElementFragment fgt = FlowElementFragment.newInstance(fe);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.flowstate_fragment_container, fgt)
                    .commit();
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        }


    }
```

**FlowElementFragment.java**

```
 public FlowElementFragment extends Fragment {
    public static FlowElementFragment newInstance(FlowElement e) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(FLOW_ELEMENT, e);
        FlowElementFragment fragment = new FlowElementFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You could easily test putting a Log statement inside all the onCreate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
fe = parentFlow.getChildElements() .get( fe.getNext() );
```

sounds very wrong.
Probably should be

```
fe = fe.getNext();
```

or else

```
fe = parentFlow.getChildElements().get( ++current );
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is the Activity onCreate called with each NewInstance of a fragment
>   inside it?

No.

It will be called only once.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Fragment has its functions to manage its events:

onAttached() — Called when the fragment has been associated with the activity
onCreateView() — Called to create the view for the fragment
onActivityCreated() — Called when the activity’s onCreate() method has been returned